# Not able to place the dragged element relative to the div - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/ **after dropping the element into the dropbox** if I put below code, I want the element to be at a position of 25,25 relative to the dropbox(dropboxOuter)

```
$(dragElement).animate({
            "left" : "25",  
            "top" : "25"
}, 1000 );
```

But this puts the element underneath the div ... any help

Comment: update .. http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/2/ with the above code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of bugs that I have fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/14/

- Your first problem was that your target destination wasn't on the
  same level/layer.
- You had double position (absolute & relative) on your container class
- I have set your target dropbox to absolute (to avoid other elements
  that can change the top/left value)

**Code i used to get relative drop:**

```
$(dragElement).animate({
            left: $('#dropbox').position().left + 25,
            top: $('#dropbox').position().top + 25
        }, 1000);
```